# Advantages of Acyclic Visitor over Command with Switch On Type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, open-closed-principle

The visitor pattern is useful in situations where the element hierarchy is stable and the desired functionality for operating on those elements changes often.

In cases where the element hierarchy changes, the visitor pattern suffers from coupling that forces rebuilding all classes in both the element and functionality hierarchies.

To improve on upon this, the Acyclic Visitor uses an extra level of abstraction, with an empty Visitor interface at the top, and a specific interface for each class in the element hierarchy.

Assuming two concrete element types IntMessage and StringMessage, an acyclic visitor would look like this:

```
abstract class Message // parent for the model/element/data classes
{
    public abstract void Accept(Visitor visitor);
}
class IntMessage : Message  // concrete element type 1
{
    internal int data;

    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        // check if the concrete visitor knows how to work on IntMessage
        if (visitor is IntMessageVisitor)
            (visitor as IntMessageVisitor).Visit(this);   
    }
}
class StringMessage : Message  // concrete element type 2
{
    internal String msg;
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        // check if the concrete visitor knows how to work on StringMessage
        if (visitor is StringMessageVisitor)
            (visitor as StringMessageVisitor).Visit(this);
    }
}


interface Visitor  // empty parent interface for acyclic visitor
{
}

interface IntMessageVisitor : Visitor
{
    void Visit(IntMessage message);
}
interface StringMessageVisitor : Visitor
{
    void Visit(StringMessage message);
}
```

A concrete visitor would inherit from all the specific visitor interfaces for the element types that it knows how to visit. The advantage of this is that in cases where new classes are added to the element hierarchy, only concrete visitors who need to visit the new element are forced to change.

```
class PrintVisitor : StringMessageVisitor, IntMessageVisitor
{
        public void Visit(IntMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Int message with data = " + message.data);
        }
        public void Visit(StringMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String message with data = " + message.msg);
        }
}
```

Enough setup, let's move on to the question.

**The question is**, given the complexity of the acyclic visitor pattern, does it have any real benefit over using a simple command with a switch-on-type?

For example, we could rewrite the PrintVisitor as the following print command:

```
class PrintCommand : Command
{
    public void Execute(Message message)
    {
        // switch on type
        if (message.GetType() == typeof(IntMessage))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Int message with data = " + ((IntMessage)message).data);
        }
        else
        if (message.GetType() == typeof(StringMessage))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String message with data = " + ((StringMessage)message).msg);
        }
    }
}
```

If new classes are added to the element hierarchy in the future ( for example DateMessage ), then still only the commands that want to work on the new element type will need to change. The resulting design would be much simpler, without multiple interface inheritance, and double dispatch, at the "cost" of using runtime type information instead of virtual functions.

It seems that as far as OCP and future maintenance there is no extra cost for the switch on type over the acyclic visitor.

Is there ever any reason to prefer the ACyclic Visitor over command with switch-on-type ?

Comment: `Visitor` and `Command` are *completely* different patterns addressing completely different problems. They can be combined when needed. `Visitor` isn't as useful nowadays as it used to be. You can check the type with `is`. With pattern matching you can actually get a strongly typed object, eg `if (message is IntMessage intM){ intM.....}`. The `dynamic` keyword reduced the need for `Visitor` when it was introduced at the expense of type safety. Patterns brought type safety back. If you use a `switch expression` you can use exhaustive matching to ensure all cases are covered

Comment: `Execute` can be replaced with `message switch { IntMessage intM=>$"blah {intm.data}", StringMessage stM=> $"blah {stm.msg}", _ => throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(message));`

Comment: I'm not sure whether the word `Command` here is meant to indicate the GoF design pattern; but in the GoF book, the Command pattern prohibits the `Execute()` method from accepting any parameter. The point is that clients can invoke a Command without having any additional information beyond a reference to the Command itself.

Comment: @jaco0646 That's a valid point. Yes, I am referencing a modified version of the GOF Command pattern. My point is that Command is an object that wraps functionality ( as is visitor ).

Comment: Or...  there can be just one Visitor interface that provides default no-op implementations of all the visit methods.  Easy peasy.

Comment: @MattTimmermans As far as I know , easy peasy things always come in a full answer with code examples :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no clear answer. The answer depends on your specific circumstances. Your example is relatively simple as it only involves alternatives to a single type, not alternative *families* of types. The [typical example of a Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) shows using different visitors to handle families of *multiple* different types in a tree. A good example would be visitors that render XML to HTML, PDF or word documents. Each of those visitors handles a family of elements.

In the simple example, a `Visitor` isn't that useful. It adds type safety at the expense of (significant) complexity.

Since C# 6 introduced patterns all this code can be reduced tremendously. In C# 9 `Execute` can be :

```
public static void Execute(Message message)
{
    var text=message switch { 
                 IntMessage intM=>$"blah {intM.data}", 
                 StringMessage stM=> $"blah {stM.msg}", 
                 _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown type {message.GetType()}",
                                                  nameof(message))
    };
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

First Generics, then `dynamic` and now functional features like pattern matching have reduced the need tremendously, while simplifying the code a *lot*. Functional languages rarely need visitors because the compilers can easily infer types and detect missed cases.

If C# had discriminated union, a feature eagerly anticipated but always postponed since C# 7, there wouldn't even be a need for the default case. The compiler itself would recognize missing cases.

In this example, changes can be localized to just this method.

In the renderer example though, the same well known set of elements has to be handled by each concrete visitor. The elements have well known structure. Is a visitor needed in this case?

Maybe, but it can be simplified a *lot*.

Functional features like pattern matching can easily handle multiple element types *and* multiple renderers. Any changes to the element structure can be restricted to the pattern matching code, forwarding renderer-specific calls to the concrete renderer visitors.

Except when it can't. In the simplest case, *some* kinds of renderers may require a different way of dealing with the elements. Some renderers may require visiting elements multiple times.

Or the size of the data may require different strategies when possible. When one wants to export 1M rows, the best option is to stream the rendered results instead of caching them in memory. Excel though is a ZIP package, so the results need to be collected before they can be exported. In this case, even though the structure and the renderers are the same, different data sizes require different implementations.

Comment: The idea of the Acyclic visitor is that it does not need to change when new types that are added that it does not need to visit. To mirror that, the switch on type should not necessarily throw an exception when it encounters unknown types.

Comment: I don't. The default clause exists because the `switch` expression require handling all cases. That's why I mentioned discriminated unions. In other cases, eg when using tuples, it's possible to write exhaustive cases that fail to compile when something changes. The visitor on the other hand introduces a **lot** of complexity only to enforce compile-time checking. Which code is easier to maintain? It depends.

Comment: I like the shortened version of execute very much. As you mentioned using dynamic presents another alternative to double dispatch.

Comment: @GonenI pattern matching though is a lot safer. `intM` is an `IntMessage` so there's no chance of calling the wrong method. The missing piece is detecting and capturing all subtypes for `IMessage`. In F#, this is available through discriminated unions. The compiler *knows* if there's eg a `DoubleMessage` and will fail to compile if that isn't handled. C# doesn't have this yet

Comment: To reiterate my point, detecting missing subtypes may not be desirable at all. You may want to keep existing "visitors" as capable of handling only the older types without code modification. At least that is one case given for the Acyclic Visitor.

Answer (score 2):

Bob Martin blogged about this very question, all the way back in 2005: http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.VisitorVersusInstanceOf. Regarding the type-checking (non-visitor) approach, he says,

> ...there are some things I don't like about this. For one thing, the chain of if/else statement will grow without bound as more and more derivatives are added to the system. It takes time to execute the [type-checking] statement, and on average we will have to execute about half of them... This means that the runtime complexity is O(n), where n is the number of derivatives.

The derivatives he mentions are the "visitable" subclasses, which in the OP would be subclasses of `Message`. His argument boils down to performance. This does not mean an Acyclic Visitor is always preferable to plain old type-checking.

> I am not trying to make the case that Acyclic Visitor should always be used. Indeed, each of the forms we have discussed could be appropriate in various situations. I use the following decision table:
>
> |  | Context Hierarchy Changes | Visitor Hierarchy Changes | Efficiency is important |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | if/else of instanceof | no | no | no |
> | Visitor | no | yes | yes |
> | Acyclic Visitor | yes | yes | yes |

Hiding the type-checking logic behind an abstraction as shown in the OP can address the issues around hierarchy changes, meaning the only remaining issue is performance. Acyclic Visitor requires only one type check versus many in an if/else chain.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't considered performance at all. I suppose it could be an issue with a hierarchy of hundreds of classes, of say a product catalog for an enterprise, where each class represents a product. ( based on actual work experience ). Then again, I doubt anyone would code a hundred line switch.